# MonoMac: Best way to convert Bitmap to NSImage

Tags: bitmap, nsimage, monomac

Since MonoMac doesnt have own class Bitmap, i need the best ways to convert image from Bitmap to NSImage.
Current my way is:

```
byte[] bytes = SomeFuncReturnsBytesofBitmap();
NSData imageData = NSData.FromArray(bytes);
NSImage image = new NSImage(imageData);
imageView.Image = image;
```

Answer (score 4):

From: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-osx/2011-July/004436.html

```cs
public static NSImage ToNSImage(this Image img) {
        System.IO.MemoryStream s = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        img.Save(s, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] b = s.ToArray();
        CGDataProvider dp = new CGDataProvider(b,0,(int)s.Length);
        s.Flush();
        s.Close();
        CGImage img2 = CGImage.FromPNG(dp,null,false,CGColorRenderingIntent.Default);
        return new NSImage(img2, new SizeF(img2.Width,img2.Height));
    }
```

**EDIT:**

And to convert from an NSImage to Image

```cs
 public static Image ToImage(this NSImage img) {
        using (var imageData = img.AsTiff()) { 
            var imgRep = NSBitmapImageRep.ImageRepFromData(imageData) as NSBitmapImageRep;
            var imageProps = new NSDictionary();
            var data = imgRep.RepresentationUsingTypeProperties(NSBitmapImageFileType.Png, imageProps);
            return Image.FromStream(data.AsStream());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With `NSImage.FromStream` Herman's solution can be simplified. I assume it wasn't available when the question was posted.

```cs
public static NSImage ToNSImage(this Image img) {
    using (var s = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
        img.Save(s, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        s.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return NSImage.FromStream(s);
    }
}
```